# How is the exit command properly executed in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, console, rubygems, executable

I have been trying to create a Ruby gem that simply exits my terminal whenever "x" is entered. Here is my main project file:

```
module SwissKnife
  VERSION = '0.0.1'

  class ConsoleUtility
    def exit
      `exit`
    end
  end
end
```

and my executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'swissknife'

util = SwissKnife::ConsoleUtility.new
util.exit
```

For some reason whenever I run this nothing appears to happen. I debugged it by adding in a simple `puts 'Hello World!'` in there, and it would print "Hello World!" but not exit. What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Backticks execute code in a new shell
2. `exit` isn't an executable that your shell runs, it's a special command understood by your shell - telling it to exit

So when you do

```
`exit`
```

it starts a shell which immediately exits. Not very useful. To exit the shell, you can instead kill Ruby's parent process.

```
Process.kill 'HUP', Process.ppid
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to send commands to the shell running Ruby, but you can kill the shell process. See my edit.